# How to create one tab that affects 2 different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bigcommerce

I got a BigCommerce store setup. Now I'm creating 4 tabs (represent 4 different colors of product: gold, grey, dark grey and black). I have set up that when click on each tab, that product's photo of the same color will appear. Here is the code:

```
  <ul class="CCW-tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">
    <img src="/template/images/CCW-Color-Gold.png" alt="Antique Brass LED Picture Light" />
    <div style="text-align:left;margin-top:18px;">Antique Brass</div>
  </a></li>

  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">
    <img src="/template/images/CCW-Color-Satin.png" alt="Satin Nickle LED Picture Light"/>
    <div style="text-align:left;margin-top:18px;">Satin Nickle</div>
  </a></li>

  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">
    <img src="/template/images/CCW-Color-Bronze.png" alt="Oil Rubbed Bronze LED Picture Light"/>
    <div style="text-align:left;margin-top:18px;">Oil Rubbed Bronze</div>
  </a></li>

  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Apple')">
    <img src="/template/images/CCW-Color-Black.png" alt="Black LED Picture Light"/>
    <div style="text-align:left;margin-top:18px;">Black</div>
  </a></li>
</ul>
```

Those are tabs to link to these photos

```
<div id="London" class="CCW-tabcontent"><img src="/template/images/CCW-BSL21AB.jpg" alt="Battery Picture Light" />                    
</div>
<div id="Paris" class="CCW-tabcontent"><img src="/template/images/CCW-BSL21AB-Silver.jpg" alt="Battery Picture Light" /> 
</div>
<div id="Tokyo" class="CCW-tabcontent"><img src="/template/images/CCW-BSL21AB-Dark-Silver.jpg" alt="Battery Picture Light" />                    
</div>
<div id="Apple" class="CCW-tabcontent"><img src="/template/images/CCW-BSL21AB-Black.jpg" alt="Battery Picture Light" /></div>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
    <script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("CCW-tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

I'm using the Skeleton framework that divide in 12 columns. The first 6 columns for the product photo and and second 6 columns for the product color tabs. Now here is the problem:

- I have the "ADD TO CART" button right below the color tabs. I want every time when we hit the color tab, the correct product's photo AND the correct "ADD TO CART" button appear at the same time. (There are 4 "ADD TO CART" buttons as well).

So here what I have tried:
[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEj55.png)

I added the "ADD TO CART" button under the same `<div>` of the product photo, which the button would be on the wrong side.

I then tried this: [photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HfAi.png)

Now the button is on the correct side, but the photo disappeared.

How do I make the color tab works for both product's photo AND the "ADD TO CART" button at the same time? Or any other solution here?

Comment: Hey Trung, I didn't get a chance to review your code yet; but I wanted to say that BigCommerce natively supports changing the product image based on the selected option. You would first create an option set that contains those 4 colors as product variations. Then you can apply rules so that once one of the options is selected, the product image will change to w photo you upload. This way the only code you need to write would just be to change the option/variation button to your own custom color image (gold, grey, etc). Let me know if this potentially works for you.

Comment: Hi Root. Thank you for your answer. That actually works. However, my manager wanted me to create 4 custom pages (with 4 different colors), so I have to use custom code for this (due to some limitation from BigCommerce). I wonder if I can use 2 onclick events on one element? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Trung, you wouldn't want to use two separate click events, you should just have one click event responsible for performing both the actions. Is there any reason why it cannot be structured like that?

Comment: Hi Root. You're right. Using 2 onclick events on one element isn't a good idea. I, however, figured out the way to make it work (the first one as described above, the 2nd which for the "ADD TO CART" button, I used Bootstrap's javascript framework). The reason I couldn't use the feature installed in BigCommerce is my manager wanted me to customize the whole page (for some reason he does not like some of BigCommerce features - which I kinda understand). Anyways, your solution gives me another option to consider if I ever get stuck again. Thanks again, Root.